# Finding angle between two lines subjected to conditions on their direction cosines

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Find the angle between two lines . Their dc's follow given conditions. $$  l+m+n=0$$  $$2lm+2ln-mn=0$$. $$\text {Attempt} $$ we know two conditions and third one is obvious ie $l^2+m^2+n^2=1$. Squaring $1$ and using given equations we have $$1+3mn=0$$ thus $$mn=-\frac {1}{3}$$. From there $$2l (m+n)+\frac {1}{3}=0$$ thus $$2l^2=\frac {1}{3} $$ giving $l=\pm \frac {1}{\sqrt {6}} $. From here the real confusion starts. I dont know how to continue as using two different values for l gives tqo different values of m each. So now the question is what exact values of l,m need to be used to find the values of n . This becomes quite cumbersome. This attempt isnt giving a neat solution. Is there a more cleaner way to solve this?

Comment: What're the direction cosines for the second line?

Comment: Both lines have same conditions on dcs.

Comment: Let $\mathbf{n}_1=(l,m,n)$, $$\cos \theta=\mathbf{n}_1 \cdot \mathbf{n}_2$$